# Ubuntu - Identifying a logged in user's bash session

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, login, user-management

I'm trying to delete a user logged into my ubuntu system. Let's call the user bob.

I'm running

```
sudo userdel -r bob
```

The response I get is

```
userdel: user bob is currently logged in
```

So I run

```
ps -u bob
```

To find his bash session to kill it. But I'm not seeing it - I'm looking for something like:

```
13205 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

(Which is my session) but I don't see another one:

What command can I run to find out what this user is logged in as?

---

Edit:

```
who bob
```

gives no result (to stdout at least)

```
last bob
```

gives a result three days ago - but running

```
sudo userdel -r bob
```

Still gives the same result.

---

Edit

```
who
```

only gives my login.

---

Edit

```
root@machine:~# sudo userdel -rf bob
userdel: user bob is currently logged in
userdel: warning: can't remove /var/mail/bob: No such file or directory
userdel: error removing directory /
root@machine:~# sudo userdel -rf bob
userdel: user 'bob' does not exist
```

This seems like it was not a correct type of user - is that correct?

Comment: What do `last bob` and `who` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `sudo userdel -rf bob` work?  If not, what error does it give?

Comment: Best answer so far...

Answer (score 1):

The `who` command should work.

Or you could display all processes belong to bob with `ps -au bob`.

Comment: who just displays my login. ps -au bob displays all running processes.

Answer (score 1):

Run ps command:

```
ps auxwwwf | less
```

then press '/bob' and press enter(to search):

```
ooshro    4465  0.0  0.6 223480 19348 ?        Rl   Feb18   1:19 gnome-terminal
ooshro    4466  0.0  0.0  14488   792 ?        S    Feb18   0:00  \_ gnome-pty-helper
ooshro    4467  0.0  0.1  22116  4884 pts/1    Ss   Feb18   0:00  \_ bash

root      1208  0.0  0.0  71268  2040 tty2     Ss   Feb18   0:00 /bin/login --       
ooshro   18088 10.5  0.1  22176  4932 tty2     S+   17:40   0:00  \_ -bash

root       579  0.0  0.5   5632  2192 ?        Ss   09:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       706  0.0  0.7   8432  2784 ?        Ss   11:57   0:00  \_ sshd: ooshro [priv] 
ooshro     722  0.0  0.3   8564  1308 ?        S    11:57   0:02      \_ sshd: ooshro@pts/0  
ooshro     723  0.0  1.3   9808  5220 pts/0    Ss   11:57   0:00          \_ -bash
```

Comment: This only gives my processes, but sudo userdel -r bob still claims that they're logged in.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty

`ps fuxaw |grep ^bob | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

this will kill all bobs processes, so you can proceed with deleting the account.

Comment: This gave an error saying kill didn't have proper arguments... output Usage: ... etc

Comment: that means that there were no processes of user bob to kill

Answer (score 0):

track down the session off the user

```
ps -u | grep bob
```

and then kill them.

Or, i you are feeling confident:

```
kill -15 $(ps -U bob -o "pid=")
```

Otherwise, you could try forcing the userdel by adding the -f option.